# How to plot certain row values from multiple dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have 10 dfs with same column names. They look like the following:

```
country_code   country  x    y                                      
SVN     Slovenia  29.794   21.041
ESP        Spain  380.429  176.025
SWE       Sweden  43.313   38.123
CHE  Switzerland  173.884   67.118
GBR           UK  630.777  202.434
```

I want to plot x values for a particular country from the 10 dfs. What would be the elegant way to do this?

I tried concanting dfs and then grouping by country_code.

```
keys = np.arange(1,11)
result = pd.concat(frames, keys=keys)

grouped = result.groupby(["country_code"])

fig, axs = plt.subplots(10, sharex=True)
for ax, (key, frame) in zip(axs, agg_ita):
     frame = frame.droplevel(0)
     frame.plot(ax=ax)
     ax.set_title(f'{key}')
fig.tight_layout()
```

Comment: You tried concatenation the dfs and what happened? What do you expect to see?

Comment: Why not filter the concatenated df if you need a particular country? `result[result['country'] == 'UK']['x'].plot()`

Comment: @RJAdriaansen Thanks for the suggestion. This is what I was trying to extract.